# Puppet installing packages, but these do not seem to work

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, puppet, yeoman, bower

I have the following puppet file. It seems to have installed everything without errors, but commands such as `yo` or `bower` dont seem to work. Any idea why?

```
class yeoman {
    Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }

    $yeomanPackages = ["git", "rubygems", "libjpeg-turbo-progs", "optipng", "phantomjs", "python-software-properties" ]

    package { $yeomanPackages:
      ensure => "installed",
      require => Exec['apt-get update'],
    }
    exec { "apt-get update":
      command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
    }
    package { 'compass':
      ensure   => latest,
      provider => 'gem',
      require  =>  Package["rubygems"],
    }
    package { 'yo':
      ensure => present,
      provider => 'npm',
      require => Class["nodejs"],
    }
    package { 'grunt-cli':
      ensure => present,
      provider => 'npm',
      require => Class["nodejs"],
    }
    package { 'bower':
      ensure => present,
      provider => 'npm',
      require => Class["nodejs"],
    }
}
include nodejs
include yeoman
```

I have used the following nodejs module:
https://forge.puppetlabs.com/willdurand/nodejs

Running yo / bower prints out:

```
-bash: yo: command not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't the down voter, but what exactly happens when you try to execute the yo or bower commands?

Comment: It prints out 
-bash: yo: command not found - I have updated the post

Comment: I have the same problem, keep an eye on this pull request which I believe fixes it: https://github.com/willdurand/puppet-nodejs/pull/30#issuecomment-27811427

Comment: This should be fixed now.